# How to ensure that our website is not vulnerable to the issue SUPEE-6482 after installing the patches?

Tags: security, patches, secure

I've installed the patch SUPEE-6482, but still appear a window like this:

[image: SUPEE-6482]

Whether it means the patch is not installed correctly? How to ensure that our website/Magento is secure from the patch issue?
I mean sample case on release notes of SUPEE-6482 (two issues related to APIs and two cross-site scripting risks), whether sufficient in tests on web like https://shoplift.byte.nl/ or need special check?

Comment: This is just the default admin panel message that pops up. You need to either mark as read or delete the message inside the message inbox in your Magento admin panel.

Comment: Thanks @benn1th, I know that it is a message pop up from Magento and how to remove it or disable that message.
I mean sample case on the release notes of SUPEE-6482 (two issues related to APIs and two cross-site scripting risks) from, whether sufficient in tests on web like https://shoplift.byte.nl/ or special need to check?

Comment: Check in `app/etc/applied.patches.list` to see what is reported as installed, check the file dates on the patched files to make sure they match the application date in the list or open the patch and manually verify that the changes were made to the listed files. The Admin notification doesn't have any intelligence that is able to detect that patches are installed. It's just a notification that you need to manually verify your patches were installed. The ShopLift tester is for a way earlier patch, has nothing to do with the latest API patch and doesn't test for it.

Comment: Thanks @fiasco-labs, but I can't find / there's no applied.patches.list in `app/etc/`

Comment: Then its questionable whether any patches have ever been applied to this Magento installation. Magento patches create this file and append their patch results to it.

Comment: @fiasco-labs, I update the patch does not through the shell so that the file does not exist. I copy and paste from the zip file. So may be how to make sure the patch is to compare files in manually replace?

Comment: Yes, then the only way to check is to physically diff the patched file against one freshly extracted from an installer archive file that matches your installed version. Or else the file date for that particular file must match the patched file that you uploaded.

Comment: @fiasco-labs, thanks for the help. With this I can be sure and know how to check after the installation of the next patch or update.